# Pandas - drop row where two columns equal each other?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I drop a a row when the values in 2 of the columns are equal?

Many thanks.

Comment: Provide some examples with code

Comment: Try this: `df = df[ df['col1'] != df['col2'] ]`

Comment: @hacker315 many thanks it worked(thought I had tried that. Did try this:
df.drop_duplicates(subset=["col1","col2"]) but didn't work. Any ideas?